# Repeating decimal. 0.01234567901234

Tags: mathematics

Express the repeating base-10 decimal number $ 0.0123456790123456790... $ as a fraction $ \dfrac{1}{x} $ in any base system up to hexadecimal such that $ x $ has a minimal number of only 0s and 1s.

Comment: I attempted to clarify what your question is. Check my edit note for more details

Comment: Isn't this a math question?

Comment: @TzuLi Unless there's a [clever or elegant solution with an "aha" moment](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2784/5373).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fraction is

> $\frac{1}{81}$

Which can be expressed

> in base $9$ as $\frac{1}{100}$

Comment: Not bad. It's optimal if I'm not mistaken.